# I want to style the Button Component with some properties but I see I can't use classname in updated MUI5

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
import { styled } from "@mui/system";
import DeleteIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Delete";
import SendIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Send";
import { Button } from "@mui/material";


const Button = styled("button")({
  color: "red",
  backgroundColor: "black",
  padding: "1rem",
});

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        size="medium"
        startIcon={<DeleteIcon />}
        endIcon={<SendIcon />}
      >
        Material UI
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

> I think styled is now a new way in MUI to create make and use custom
> styles. I don't think    I can use className property in this case.
> Previously I could use makeStyles and useStyles and assign classname
> to the Button component to customize it, How can I use Button
> Component from MUI and customize it using styled . Right now I should
> define at the top what kind of component is. I want to use Button component, its variant color properties and also customize it using styled.

Comment: why don't you use sx ?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `sx` to add css to components in MUI 5

```
  <Button
    sx={{color: "red",
    backgroundColor: "black",
    padding: "1rem"}}
    variant="contained"
    size="medium"
    startIcon={<DeleteIcon />}
    endIcon={<SendIcon />}
  >
    Material UI
  </Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple of problems here:

1. you need to make sure that you import as follows:

```
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
```

https://mui.com/material-ui/migration/migrating-from-jss/

2. since you want to customize the mui, pass the `Button` to `styled` and rename the component

```
const CustomButton = styled(Button)({
  color: "red",
  backgroundColor: "black",
  padding: "1rem",
});
```

Then you can use it

```
function App() {
  return (
      <CustomButton
        variant="contained"
        size="medium"
        startIcon={<DeleteIcon />}
        endIcon={<SendIcon />}
      >
        Material UI
      </CustomButton>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the code below

```
const StyledButton = styled(Button)(() => ({
  color: "red",
  backgroundColor: "black",
  padding: "1rem",
}));
```

In the first `()` you need to pass the material ui component as the named export and then you can use the const-name.
So in your code in stead of `<Button></Button>` you will use the `<StyledButton></StyledButton>`

Usage:

```
<StyledButton
  variant="contained"
  size="medium"
  startIcon={<DeleteIcon />}
  endIcon={<SendIcon />}
>
  Material UI
</StyledButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `!important` to overwrite styles and `styled(Button)` as it is clear in code. complete version is [here in sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-mopsa-zfqo5?file=/src/App.js:0-567)

```
    import * as React from "react";
import { styled } from "@mui/styles";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import DeleteIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Delete";
import SendIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Send";

const MyButton = styled(Button)({
  backgroundColor: "#000 !important",
  color: "red !important",
  padding: "1rem !important"
});

export default function App() {
  return (
    <MyButton
      variant="contained"
      size="medium"
      startIcon={<DeleteIcon />}
      endIcon={<SendIcon />}
    >
      Styled Components
    </MyButton>
  );
}
```

[image]